# Understanding Closure and Methodology

Tags: javascript, parsing, closures, interpreter, evaluation

I'm building a interpreter and i'm now at the point where I need to implement it to handle closures. I understand the concept pretty well but I have a question on why they're designed the way they are.

In terms of how a closure is designed/interpreted there needs to be 3 things:

1. variable
2. body of logic that variable is bound to
3. environment that is saved during the closure's instantiation, this is for free variables that exist within the body to be bound when the closure variable is evaluated.

I understand why all of these things are needed, i'm just wondering about why the 3rd item is needed at all when substitution at the moment of the closure's creation is doing the same thing? Is there anything i'm not accounting for?

Essentially what i'm asking is why not just substitute the free variables with the respective environment values at closure creation instead of passing the environment entirely?

Comment: Are you writing a JavaScript interpreter in JavaScript or an interpreter for another language with closures in JavaScript or a JavaScript interpreter in another language or what? It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: I'm writing an interpreter in javascript but I  tried ask it in a general sense. The language is irrelevant.

Comment: The value of the captured (free) variable(s) can change before the closure is executed. Indeed, two closures can capture the same variable and modify it, leading to a sort of intercommunication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I guess it's a little late, but oh well...*

That depends on your computation model (evaluation strategy for example).
If all the data structures [which can get bound by a variable, and in effect enclosed] are immutable in your language your method should work.
It works with pure lexical lisp dialects (eg functional subset of scheme), nice and smooth.

It might not work if:

- You pass arguments by reference, as was already mentioned in the comments. Call by value is fine. Also references to immutable object are fine.
- Your environment binding and/or lookup causes some side effect. That would be rather exotic, but who knows?

Also, mind you don't have to enclose entire environment, just the free variables of your function's body (easy!).

The only reasons [I am aware of] for implementing closures as body+environment are:

- you might want to pass references to mutable objects. This happens i.a. with dictionaries in js and python; it is a bit scary to have closure changing over time, but oh well.
- you don't need to write substitution function. Mind it has to keep the scoping correct, so would have to resemble your evaluation function [if your computational model is substitutional] -- so why repeat yourself? Also there is this delicate nature of values: in case of applicative order ("eager evaluation") when you substitute the value in the body, you need it to be lifted to expression who's value is the thing (if by any chance you are implementing LISP variant, think about symbols -- you don't substitute the value `HI!`, but the expression `(quote HI!)`. This does not apply to cases when all your datastructures evaluate to themselves, like numbers or truth values in most LISPs). These are not problems in general, but introduce some complexity to your interpreter, and **simple is good**.
- the bound value might be something memory-consuming, and the variable you enclose occurs [as a free variable] more than once -- you body will be significantly larger (e.g. your value is a bitmap or sound sample or some enormous matrix or... you get the picture). It is similar problem to computation duplication with lazy evaluation, but wrt memory, not time. This is also usualy not a problem as computer memories are big.

I've ran out of ideas what else might break, but if you're not into checking your computation model "on paper" (by equational reasoning) you should implement it and try the trickiest cases [if any of these applies]: side effects, lazy evaluation, references, mutable objects, combinations of the above. They are definitely not obstacles, just places worth checking.
Hope that helps, good luck with your interpreter!

PS If you like to think about this kind of stuff, check out defunctionalization (["Defunctionalization at Work"](http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/23/BRICS-RS-01-23.pdf) by Danvy and Nielsen is a pretty accessible read, and you should be fine with first part to get some inspiration)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I appreciate it.